# Weird Radio Station Coming Through My Amp

Tags: amplifiers

I have a fender mustang III Amp and I recently bought a used Washburn Bad Dog Wah pedal. When I plugged in the amp, wah, and guitar a strange radio or news channel station started playing through my amp talking about the president impeachment. I don't have cable in my apartment and I didn't have any radio stations on. As soon as I lifted the wah pedal off the ground it went away and haven't been able to find it since. I have a video of it but it really freaked me out but was kinda cool. Has anyone else experienced something like this or know how this could have happened.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this could be from bad grounding in the building. When I was in Uni, I could hear someone watching a basketball game through my amp. However, I could only notice it when I had higher gain and some distortion.

The Tv/Radio might be coming up in your amp but you just can't hear it until the Wah pedal amplifies it.

Another problem, may actually just be that the amp isn't properly shielded. I don't think it is the pedal specifically though.